# I'd like to use a drupal-like taxonomy system on external script

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy

For my site, i would add a category system to organize content just like the drupal taxonomy.
Do something like this already exist?

Comment: This question is pretty vague. Drupal's taxonomy system does a lot of different things (data structure, UI, querying, etc.) Which part(s) do you want? And in what context (custom PHP, other CMS, etc.) do you want to use this?

Comment: Context => custom php.
things => all :D

However, it looks like it would be really hard to do that my own =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should code these tables:
1. taxonomy vocabulary (vocabulary id, name)
2. taxonomy terms (term id, name, vocabulary id, order)
3. taxonomy link to your content (term id, content id)

And you should have content table, that has content id.

Now you should write code that will add/delete/edit vocabularies and terms. In content editing you should provide linking to term (selecting vocabulary somewhere or here and assign term id -> add to 3rd table).

After this you should provide listing of terms, listing of content type that has some term and etc...


p.s. Use drupal instead of your own code, because drupal tested by hundreds of developers in more than 10 000 hours, than your code with 1 people in less than 100 hours :)